# Firestore Golang run query with filters in transaction

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I can't figure out how to run a `firestore.Query` in a transaction in the Golang Admin SDK.

The `firestore.Transaction` has a `GetAll()` method that takes an array of `*firestore.DocumentRef`, which I assume is how one would query multiple documents in a transaction. This works if I want to query an entire collection, since I can use `tx.DocumentRefs` to convert a `*firestore.CollectionRef` into document refs but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent method for queries (for example if I want to filter the collection).

In the NodeJS Admin SDK I could do something like:

```js
admin.firestore().runTransaction(async (t) => {
  const fooCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('foos').where('bar', '==', true);
  const foosSnapshot = await t.get(fooCollectionRef);

  // do stuff with the foos
})
```

How can I accomplish the same in Golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Transaction.Documents` method. It accepts a `Queryier` which can be a `firestore.Query`. See this method in the docs https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Transaction.Documents
Following is a simple example:

```
err := client.RunTransaction(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, tx *firestore.Transaction) error {
  col := client.Collection("myCollection")
  query := col.Where("myCondition", "==", 1)
  docs := tx.Documents(query)
  for {
    d, err := docs.Next()
    if err != nil {
      if err == iterator.Done {
        break
      }
      //handle error
    }
    //do something with the document
  }
  return nil
})

if err != nil {
  // handle error.
}
```